# Javascript - Add a value to a display line

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to add another value i.e naym, to the display line after total based on the value of cur i.e if cur = 1 then naym = 'hello' else naym = 'goodbye'

```
function changeCounter(cur, total) {

    document.getElementById("counter").setAttribute('align', 'center');
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = cur + "/" + total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeCounter(cur, total) {

    if(cur==1){
        naym = 'hello';
    }
    else
        naym = 'goodbye';

    document.getElementById("counter").setAttribute('align', 'center');
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = cur + "/" + total+"("+naym+")";
}
```

Comment: Thank you thats perfect, however If have more than 2 options. could you amend this code to include an elseif for cur = 2 ?

Comment: Have sussed it out. Many Thanks @ashkufaraz for a prompt and accurate answer

Comment: Your well come .if this answer is correct please accept it